# How to automatically merge .hgtags in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge, dvcs, merge-conflict-resolution, .hgtags

I have a script running some Mercurial commands in non-interactive mode on a build server. One of the commands merges two branches and there is always a conflict in the `.hgtags` file during the merge because of the way the build scripts are set up.

How can I force Mercurial to always merge the `.hgtags` file using changes from both files, first from one, then from the other?

For example, if I the files to merge were

```
A
B
C
```

and

```
A
B
D
```

I would like the result to be

```
A
B
C
D
```

I am guessing I will need a custom merge tool. What tool provides this functionality?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Please see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012910/110204) by Magras de La Mancha for better solution with Mercurial 3.1.* The below is a simpler and more naive solution for older versions of Mercurial.

---

Yes, you need to configure a custom [merge tool](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) for your `.hgtags` file. Mercurial doesn't  provide any special merge tool for `.hgtags`, you're expected to merge it by hand using your normal three-way merge tool.

Conflicts in the `.hgtags` file can have two types:

- **Silly conflicts:** This is the situation you have and there is not really a conflict here. What happens is that one branch has

  ```
  f40273b0ad7b3a6d3012fd37736d0611f41ecf54 A
  0a28dfe59f8fab54a5118c5be4f40da34a53cdb7 B
  12e0fdbc57a0be78f0e817fd1d170a3615cd35da C
  ```

  and the other branch has

  ```
  f40273b0ad7b3a6d3012fd37736d0611f41ecf54 A
  0a28dfe59f8fab54a5118c5be4f40da34a53cdb7 B
  979c049974485125e1f9357f6bbe9c1b548a64c3 D
  ```

  Each tag refers to exactly one changeset, so there's no conflict here. The merge should of course be the *union* on of the two files:

  ```
  f40273b0ad7b3a6d3012fd37736d0611f41ecf54 A
  0a28dfe59f8fab54a5118c5be4f40da34a53cdb7 B
  12e0fdbc57a0be78f0e817fd1d170a3615cd35da C
  979c049974485125e1f9357f6bbe9c1b548a64c3 D
  ```
- **Real conflicts:** There one branch has

  ```
  f40273b0ad7b3a6d3012fd37736d0611f41ecf54 A
  0a28dfe59f8fab54a5118c5be4f40da34a53cdb7 B
  12e0fdbc57a0be78f0e817fd1d170a3615cd35da C
  ```

  and the other branch has

  ```
  f40273b0ad7b3a6d3012fd37736d0611f41ecf54 A
  0a28dfe59f8fab54a5118c5be4f40da34a53cdb7 B
  979c049974485125e1f9357f6bbe9c1b548a64c3 C
  ```

  There is a real conflict here: `hg tag C` was done on both branches, but the tags refer to different changesets. Resolving this is a manual task.

If you can guarantee that you'll only have *silly conflicts* and that you only have one tag per changeset, then you can use

```
hg log -r "tagged()" --template "{node} {tags}\n" > .hgtags
```

to generate a new `.hgtags` file. The key insight is that Mercurial **knows how to merge tags** internally! It does this all the time when you have two heads with different `.hgtags` files. The above template simply generates a new `.hgtags` file based on this internal merge.

If you might have more than one tag per changeset, then the above wont work — all the tags are printed on one line so you get a tag `foo bar` instead of two tags `foo` and `bar`. You can then use this [style file](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) instead:

```
changeset = "{tags}"
tag = "{node} {tag}\n"
```

It outputs one line per *tag*, not changeset. You save this style somewhere and configure a merge tool:

```
[merge-tools]
hgtags.executable = hg
hgtags.args = log -r "tagged()" --style ~/tmp/tags-style > $output
hgtags.premerge = False
hgtags.priority = -1000

[merge-patterns]
.hgtags = hgtags
```

You now have automatic tag merges. There are some caveats:

1. **Three or more heads:** The technique only works if you have **two heads** at the time of merging. If you have three heads or more, it's possible for a deleted tag to re-appear. If you have heads X, Y, and Z, and the tag `A` is deleted in X, then Mercurial is normally able to figure out that `A` is deleted overall. It does this based on a `000...0 A` line in the `.hgtags` file in X. However, if you merge X and Y to get W, then the approach suggested will not contain any such `000...0 A` line. The definition of `A` from Z will now suddenly take effect and re-introduce `A`.
2. **Real conflicts:** If you have real conflicts in `.hgtags`, then the above method will **silently pick the tag from the most recent head** for you. The merge tool basically saves `hg tags` in `.hgtags`, and the behavior of `hg tags` with multiple heads is [explained in the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Tag#How_do_tags_work_with_multiple_heads.3F). Since `hg tags` unconditionally reads and silently merges the `.hgtags` file from all heads, there's nothing we can do about it with this simple approach. Dealing with this would require a bigger script that reads the two `.hgtags` files and detects the conflict.

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/xrstf/tagsmerger/wiki/Home for a merge tool that resolves silly conflicts. :)

Comment: @xrstf: I actually saw this the other day. I didn't recommend it since I don't think it works correctly when there are more than two heads. Simply deleting the `000...0` lines will re-introduce tags like I explain in my answer.

Comment: Excellent, I applaud! Can I ask, when this notrs will appear on Aragost's site? We'll lost it here

Comment: @LazyBadger: Thanks! Putting this kind of information on aragost.com could make sense and I would of course like to drive more people to our site. But I'm also considering to make a page at aragost.com that will point back to my favorite Stack Overflow questions so that I have something to point clients to. I'm not sure which way I'll go yet.

Comment: When I add this to `[merge-tools]`, mercurial starts using it for all merges because all the default merge tools have negative priorities. I had to add `gvimdiff.priority = 1` to the `[merge-tools]` section to get around this, as discussed in [this thread](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/merge-patterns-not-configured-correctly-td804520.html).

Comment: WARNING! This solution is slightly incorrect, as pointed out by talljosh above. Mercurial gives the minimum priority to the "original" merge tool by default, so hgtags merge will be called every time! You need to also set "merge.priority=1" to set it higher than 0 so that for non hgtags files it is called before your custom merge

Comment: @YMA Thanks, I've updated the answer with a `hgtags.priority = -1000`. I don't have time to test this right now, so please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Special thanks for `hg log -r "tagged()" --template "{node} {tags}\n" > .hgtags`, I use it to clean up tags with zero hashes.

Answer (score 13):

Mercurial 3.1 (2014-08-01) introduced **internal:tagmerge**. It's marked as experimental so be careful.
Here is preamble from [changeset](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/rev/50e20154cb68) (you can find more details about algorithm if you follow the link):

> Add a new internal:tagmerge merge tool which implements an automatic merge algorithm for mercurial's tag files
>
> The tagmerge algorithm is able to resolve most merge conflicts that currently would trigger a .hgtags merge conflict. The only case that it does not (and cannot) handle is that in which two tags point to different revisions on each merge parent *and* their corresponding tag histories have the same rank (i.e. the same length). In all other cases the merge algorithm will choose the revision belonging to the parent with the highest ranked tag history. The merged tag history is the combination of both tag histories (special care is taken to try to combine common tag histories where possible).
>
> The algorithm also handles cases in which tags have been manually removed from the .hgtags file and other similar corner cases.
>
> In addition to actually merging the tags from two parents, taking into account the base, the algorithm also tries to minimize the difference between the merged tag file and the first parent's tag file (i.e. it tries to make the merged tag order as as similar as possible to the first parent's tag file order).

*tagmerge* works only with tag files, so to use it you should set *merge-patterns*. To do this on per command basis use *--config* option:

`hg merge -r REV --config merge-patterns..hgtags=internal:tagmerge`

Or to do this on per repository basis add to your repo config `.hg/hgrc` this:

```
[merge-patterns]
.hgtags=internal:tagmerge
```

Comment: Do newer releases of Mercurial default to using this algorithm when merges involve `.hgtags` files?

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to merge the .hgtags file.  It can be different on different branches and Mercurial will correctly list all tags across all branches.

We use the [`merge-patterns` configuration option](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#merge-patterns) to tell Mercurial to use the local branch when doing merges of .hgtags.  Add the following to your repository's hgrc file:

```
 [merge-patterns]
 .hgtags = internal:local
```

When doing a merge involving the .hgtags file, .hgtags will show as modified, but not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not automatically resolve merge-conflicts by performing unattended merge.** Without merge (i.e. selecting "only my" or "only other") it will work.

I'm afraid, you have badly planned workflow - build-server **must not** perform any actions, which modify sources. It's task for human and human's choice.

But I suppose, exact data inside .hgtags have to value for build-server (it uses own clone, not populated to anybody, I hope?!), thus you can define any merge-policy in command and have (bad, with data-loss) .hgtags merged

BTW, "first from one, then from the other" in any language, using only formal logic, for pair

```
A
B
C
```

and

```
A
B
D
```

means `ABCABD` result

Comment: "first from one, then from the other" in the context of resolving a conflict usually refers to using the _conflicted_ lines from both files in the result file: first from one file, then from the other. It's a standard feature of any graphic merge tool, so I assumed everyone who had used one before would understan what I mean.

Comment: This is right "in most of the case", but, like suggested by @MartinGeisler, in this particular case a solution exists. Also, you shouldn't criticize the OP workflow without knowing more about it.

Comment: @krtek - Build server MUST NOT modify code, only build. I reserve rights to tell the truth to everybody

Comment: @LazyBadger so does that mean that a build server also cannot create a tag for the build it just did? Because that changes the source. It must be nice to live in a world with such simple rules.

Comment: @Tim Yes, can not! Inform me about results, write log. btw, illuminate repo as Christmas Tree - each sucessful (buldable) commit have tag is ugly idea. *Moved one* tag - useless

Comment: @LazyBadger We don't tag every successful build, only the ones that are deployed. The only reason the build server needs to do a merge here is that in Mercurial the revision that actually changes the list of tags is a separate revision to the tag it creates.

Comment: @Alexey - **merge for this???** Oh, my god! Clone (central?) repo (or blindly `pull -u`), build, tag, commit, push

Comment: @LazyBadger - And how do you make sure there are no other changes to the repo while you're doing that? Do you want to lock down the central repo whenever you're doing a deployable build? Even if that takes several hours? There are no easy answers to these problems. Rules like "build-server must not ... modify sources" are nice in theory, but don't work as a universal solution. Pretending that they can be applied as blanket rules in situations where you don't know the objectives or constraints is not very helpful.

Comment: @Tim - no way, but - this is not needed at all. My commit just create new tag, push without -f disallow me (Build-server) to create new head. With -f I'll get additional head, but build-master (created from proteins, not silicon) will resolve this "issue" in seconds. Can't see issue here except your wish to object me to any fines

Answer (score -1):

You should try [diffmerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/), it's awesome!

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to **automatically** merge these files.

Comment: For a *way*, you can simply edit the conflicted file as you like, but that will be a headache if there's a lot of conflicts involved, and that's why I recommended a nice tool like *diffmerge* for the OP. And there's no such tool that will help you automatically resolve a conflict, a tool will assit you in doing that.