# Mercurial workflow with stable and default branches

Tags: version-control, mercurial, continuous-integration, release-management

We are trying to migrate from Subversion to Mercurial but we are encountering some problems. First a bit of background:

**Desired workflow:**

We would like to have just two named branches, stable and default, within one repository.

- Development takes place on default branch.
- Bug fixes are committed to stable branch and merged to default.
- After every Sprint we tag our default branch.
- Eventually we can release a new version, for which we bring some code (possibly the latest Sprint tag) from default over to stable (`update stable`, `merge Sprint_xyz`), tag the branch (`tag Release_xyz`) and release.

**We also want the following jobs on our Jenkins build server for CI:**

- **End-of-Sprint job:** This job should tag default with something like Sprint_xyz
- **Release job:** This job should bring the latest "Sprint" tag changes over to the stable branch, then tag stable with something like Release_6.0.0 and build a release.

**Some more background:**

Mercurial is new to us, but for what we have seen, this seems like a sane approach. We chose tags to mark releases over named-branches and cloned-branches trying to make the development workflow as straightforward as possible (single merge step, single checkout, only a couple of branches to keep track of...).

We use scrum and potentially (but not necessarily) release a version after each sprint which may (or not) become part of the stable branch and turn into a "shipable" release.

The problem we are encountering (and which is making us wonder if we are approaching this the right way...) is the following:

We work on the default branch ('d' on the poor-man's-graph that follow):

```
d -o-o-o-o-
```

We finish a sprint and trigger an End-of-Sprint job (using Jenkins) which tags default with "Sprint 1":

```
d -o-o-o-o-o-
           |
         Sprint 1
```

To release Sprint 1 we update to stable branch ('s') and merge changes from the Sprint 1 tag revision and commit:

```
         Sprint 1
           |
d -o-o-o-o-o-
             \
s -o-o-o-o-o-o-
```

Tag stable and commit:

```
         Sprint 1
           |
d -o-o-o-o-o-
             \
s -o-o-o-o-o-o-o-
               |
             Release 1
```

Update to default and merge stable since default should stay a superset of stable, commit and push:

```
       Sprint 1
           |
d -o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-
             \   /
s -o-o-o-o-o-o-o-
               |
             Release 1
```

The problem is that when merging .hgtags from 's' to 'd' mercurial encounters a conflict which holds the release job from completing. The resulting .hgtags should contain information from both involved tags.
We have searched for a solution to this, and could probably automate these type of merge conflicts with some hooks and scripts, but it looks like an unnecessary and error-prone hack to support a workflow that otherwise seems nothing out of the ordinary.

1. Is there something inherently wrong with our approach that causes us to encounter these problems?
2. If not, what is the best way to solve these issues without having to rely on a scripts/hooks approach?
3. Is there a better approach that would support our workflow?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this link might be helpful: [A Guide to Branching in Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I already read that post. In fact our workflow was inspired but parts of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for the special case hooks. The problem you're seeing is related to the Mercurial philosophy of versioning metadata in the same way as normal repository data. This is simple and effective, and leads to a system that's overall easier to understand. But in this case it also leads to your merge conflict.

The reason it leads to a merge conflict is relatively simple. The `.hgtags` file is just a text file with a bunch of lines in it. Each line contains a hash and the associated tag. In one branch you've added the `Sprint 1` tag. In another branch you've added the `Release 1` tag. These show up as one line being added to the end of the file in one branch, and a different line being added to the end of the file in another branch.

Then you merge the two branches. Suddenly Mercurial is faced with a decision. Which line should it take? Should it take both of them? If it were source code, there would really be no way to tell without human intervention.

But it isn't source code. It's a bunch of tags. The rule should be 'if the two lines being added refer to different tags, just take both of them'. But it isn't because Mercurial is treating it like a bog-standard text file that could be important source code.

Really, the `.hgtags` file should be handled in a fairly special way for merges. And it might actually be good to add code that handles it that way into mainline Mercurial to support your use-case.

IMHO Mercurial should be modified so that the `.hgtags` file would only give you a conflict warning if you have two different hashes for the same tag. The other weird case would be if you have a tag with a hash that isn't an ancestor of the change in which the tag appears. That case should be called out somehow when doing a merge, but it isn't really a conflict.

Comment: If you see the workflow I described, when merging the Release 1 tag revision to default, why is mercurial not able to merge the changes? We do not understand this, and that's why we are reluctant to 'automate a manual merge' that mercurial should probably be able to solve by itself.

Comment: @netrunner: The `.hgtags` file is just a bunch of lines of text. On one side of the merge, one line was added to this text file. On the other side, a different line. Which line should be added? If it were source code, that would be a good question and require human intervention to solve. Should it be one, the other, or both? For the `.hgtags` file, the answer is generally trivial. If each line is about a different tag, it should be both. Mercurial doesn't treat the file specially though, it treats it just like any other text file, and so it thinks human intervention is required.

Comment: @netrunner: I added a more detailed explanation to my answer. Could you read it and tell me if it makes sense?

Comment: What you say makes sense and it was also our original thought...both tags should be there, so lets write a script to handle the merge. But if we go back to asking us what is actually what we want to accomplish, the conflict is due to the fact that we have to do a merge from default to stable and back in order to bring the stable branch on par with default. Isn't there some way to do this without having to merge e.g.: replace the stable tip with some default revision?

Comment: This is what we ended up doing, as described on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9783478/473253)

Comment: @netrunner: No, there isn't really another way. That's one of the things you get because you're using named branches. That doesn't make your use of named branches bad. You're using them in exactly the right way.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're merging the tagged changeset from default to stable. If you merge the *tagging* changeset instead, you shouldn't get the merge conflict when you merge the second (probably also tagging!) changeset back to default.

Comment: Yes, we are indeed merging the tagged changeset. How can we identify the tagging changeset? Can we hg update to the tagging changeset without having to refer to the revision hash?

Comment: I guess you might be able to use something like this: `hg id -i -r'file(.hgtags)'` (possibly with an extra revset predicate to make sure you're referencing tags changes on the correct branch).

Comment: It seems that you have pointed us in the right direction to solve the specific issue we encounter when merging the branches. That being said, do you think our current approach is a good one to support our desired workflow? Or would you suggest a different approach?

Comment: It seems fine, although I don't really see why you need two tags per sprint/release.

Comment: The need for two tags is because we may not release each sprint. If we do not release a certain sprint, but in the middle of the next sprint we decide that we want to, we still can refer to it. Anyway, thanks for your answer! If there are no better proposals the next couple of days I'll accept your answer.

Comment: We ended up with Omnifarious approach as explained on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9783478/473253), but thanks anyway for your help!