# How to manage two versions of an Android app in Mercurial

Tags: android, mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

I am using Mercurial (with TortoiseHG) to manage my Android project and recently had to branch it due to the app getting a parallel, branded version with different package name.

I have done some research and succeeded in separating everything, but now after a few days I am starting to find it hard to maintain both branches. Any change in `com.myapp.firstbranch` needs to be transited to `com.myapp.secondbranch` manually.

Worse still, I have every reason to suspect that more branches are to follow, which would require me to introduce any changes and bugfixes between many branches.

**Does Mercurial and/or Tortoisehg offer any support for such situation?** A simple merge does not work, because of different package names (the VCS sees everything as separate files and puts two versions of the app in one folder).

Ideal solution would be a tool which would allow me to sync only selected parts of selected files with no regard to imports, packages and so on, just plain text replacement.

Comment: If you're separating your app and modifying the file structure - which I imply because you mention packaging renaming - conceptually they are two different things. You can always use merge tools like Meld or WinMerge or any other you'd like to merge files, but I don't know any VCS which handles what you're mentioning.

Comment: I know they are separate, and it gets worse - some resources and values are different. This is why simple merge is out of the question, I need some text-level tool to sync them.

Comment: This sounds like a scenario where [feature flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle) are a better choice than having multiple branches. Long-lived branches are a pain to manage no matter how you cut it.

Comment: Oh, this sounds promising, but any tips on implementing it for Android? I can not see how it could be used to bypass the multiple packages problem :-(

Comment: I suggest different approach (I am using it). Move whole project into separate library and then use separate class as data provider for anything that differs in those projects. Extend that class in each project and initialize it with specific project values.

Comment: This seems rational, but it won't solve the problem of multiple packages - I would still need to implement new features or bugfixes several times, for each branch :-(

Comment: You don't have branches. You have separate library where all the features and functionality are, bug fixes go there in single branch. And you have two different projects that consist only of thin shell (AndroidManifest, build files, data provider class that defines things that differ, as well as non-common resources).

Answer (score 0):

1. I can't imagine (please explain deeper), how different package name can interfere with Mercurial branches. You have different trees inside repo? Or renamed files in branches (anyway, Mercurial track renames and can correctly merge renamed files in branches)?
2. When I faced such task (maintain different customer's branches, based on historically common codebase), I finished with MQ-patchset (patch per target for customer-specific changes) and single branch with common code in changesets
3. You can create+define different merge-tools for your repo, which will merge different files according to different (**your**) policy, not just interactive merge in GIU-merger (see `internal:*` mergetools as example)

**Additions**

1. I'll ask to show (at least part of) `hg manifest` for branches (or just ls of Working Dir) (just because I know nothing about packages, it's structures and Android-development in common), but, AFAICR, if you have `/firstbranch` in initial branch, which in second branch was renamed to `/secondbranch`, Mercurial will honor this change in branch-merges. Another idea is eliminate parent-tree from versioning as much as possible and move task of creating proper tree of package into build-tool
2. No, I had "trivial" tasks of adding|changing|removing objects (customer's branding), but, from my POV, "all imports, package relations and so on" are, technically, just changes in code (and possible - trees), which patches can hold
3. Custom mergetools have to be mostly easy hand-made scripts with minimal logic in it. Try to read Wikis: [Merge Tool Configuration](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) (part 2) and [Merge Tools](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/merge-tools) as starting point and [this excellent example of creating own merge-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782383/how-to-automatically-merge-hgtags-in-mercurial/9783478#9783478) for merging .hgtags

Comment: 1. When branching the project, I had to rename the packege from lets say `com.company.firstbranch` to `com.company.secondbranch`. And it branched fine, but I can not use standard merge tool, at all it does is create directory `com.company` with two further directories, `firstbranch` and `secondbranch`.

Comment: 2. Did your task include change of package name for each branch. It **IS** important, as all imports, package relations and so on change.

Comment: 3. This one sounds promising, could you elaborate where to find these?